# Top Questions of the Week #12

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 12 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 7):

I think this one was rather good.
[How to identify whether my Linux computer was hacked?](https://superuser.com/questions/273353/was-my-linux-computer-hacked)

Comment: Definitely a great question, with lots of interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question here, [Windows 1.0 menu](https://superuser.com/questions/273895/windows-1-0-menu)